# How do I remove rounded borders in GNOME Shell?

Tags: gnome

Is there a way I can remove the rounded borders on the top left and right corners of windows on Gnome Shell? How can I do it?

Answer (score 8):

From the ArchLinux Forum:

```
edit the css in /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css 
(the .panel-corner properties).
```

The credit goes to the forum user "gimmy". Refer to the original forum in the sources below if you would like to view the entire thread.

```
Source: ArchLinux Forum - https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=138403
```

Answer (score 3):

For the people who use a custom theme: A better way is to modify the gnome-shell css file of the theme. If you use a `gnome-shell.css` file with your custom theme, edit the file with a text editor and just add these lines:

```css
.panel-corner { 
 -panel-corner-radius: 0px;
 -panel-corner-background-color: transparent;
 -panel-corner-border-width: 0px;
 -panel-corner-border-color: transparent;
}
```

"Remove Rounded Corners extension" is a good extension but sometimes it bugs with the "User Theme" extension...

Answer (score 1):

Any easier way to remove rounded corners and have it persist even after theme updates is to use the Remove Rounded Corners extension.

[Remove Rounded Corners Extension](http://markbokil.com/downloads/extensions/remove-rounded-corners/index.html)

Comment: This doesn't work in Ubuntu Precise anymore, it says that the GNOME3 there is too old.

Answer (score -1):

There is a package called [GNOME Tweak Tool](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeTweakTool) `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool` that allows you to make changes to the interface, and install new themes. You can find additional GNOME-Shell themes [here](http://gnome-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=191), and perhaps other sites as well.

Comment: Yes, I know how to change theme, but I want to change edit Adwaita theme.