# How do I remove rounded borders from windows in Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME shell?

Tags: 18.04, themes, gtk, window, gtk3

How can I make window edges squared (instead of round) in Ubuntu 18.04?  I am using the Ambiance theme.

[image]

What I tried (without any success on 18.04):

1. The solution from [How do I remove rounded borders in GNOME Shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114645/how-do-i-remove-rounded-borders-in-gnome-shell), which was from an older version of Ubuntu (11.04?) that used GNOME shell.
2. The solution from [How to make ambiance title bar corners squared?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/638399/how-to-make-ambiance-title-bar-corners-squared), which worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04 when Unity was the default.

Interestingly, the question [Rounded corners of windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029338/rounded-corners-of-windows) is trying to *remove* square corners (which it achieved by removing `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`) so presumably I need to add some code to that file.

Any ideas on what CSS code is needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the following lines to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` have made the corners square:

```
.titlebar,
.titlebar .background {
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}
```

As an alternative, you can use `border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px`.

Comment: If gnome works with proper CSS standards, `border-radius: 0` is enough. No need to define all corners, no need for a unit. 0 disables it, and it's actually the default. Have not rebooted yet, with this change, but I am pretty sure it will work.

Comment: Also, does 22.04+ use GTK 3 or 4? I think they actually use a mix or both. I have libs for 2, 3 and 4 installed. Is `~/.config/gtk-4.0/gtk.css` is this the for 4.0 as well?