# Autokey-GTK is missing a typing cursor when I use Dark Themes

Tags: themes, gnome-tweak-tool, autokey, cursor-theme, gnome-tweaks

I hoping that someone here can advise a work-around for this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/autokey/+bug/1849992) I'm experiencing in autokey-gtk.

When I use a dark theme, the phrase editor is missing its typing cursor.

I see no settings to adjust this and would appreciate any advice that would lead to me to being able to use Autokey-gtk with a dark theme, while also having a visible typing cursor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that autokey-gtk's phrase-editor is not properly inheriting the dark background prescribed by the GNOME theme. The phrase-editor's background-color remains white no matter what the GNOME theme prescribes.

Conflictingly, the autokey-gtk phrase-editor is indeed properly inheriting the caret-color (typing cursor color) from the GMONE theme. The typing-cursor is not "missing"; it is there, but because its color is the same color as the background-color, it is invisible to the human eye.

Until this theme-inheritance bug is fixed in autokey-gtk, a work-around would be to change the caret-color to a color that remains visible on the dark theme you're using. For example, you could change the caret-color to blue.

```
* {caret-color: blue; }
```

adding above line in the `.css` file of the source file made it blue color

[image]

for example to override Yaru-Dark theme

navigate to `/usr/share/themes/Yaru-Dark/gtk-3.20/gtk-dark.css` and add the below line under the line `@import url("resource:///com/ubuntu/themes/Yaru/3.20/gtk-dark.css");`

```
* {caret-color: blue; }
```

[image]

to apply this line `* {caret-color: blue; }` to all the theme files (globally)
just put this line in the file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`

[image]

reference: https://askubuntu.com/a/1159560/739431

Comment: I added your work-around to the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/autokey/+bug/1849992) (comment 7). Thank you!