# Typing/Text Cursor Thickness and Color

Tags: cursor, text

Using Ubuntu 20.04. When using LibreOffice Writer, the text/typing cursor (thin vertical line indicating the insertion point in the sentence) is very difficult to see.

How to make it:-

1. thicker ?
2. a color that is easy to see ?

I was able to get it to blink....which is a slight improvement.

(Have searched in Ask Ubuntu and on internet; but very few and very old posts...none helpful for Ubuntu 20.04).

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1185289/739431 this may partly solves..

Answer (score 0):

To make the text cursor thicker in a GTK3 based desktop (including standard Ubuntu, Budgie, XFCE), edit or create a configuration file `.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` and add the line:

```
* { -GtkWidget-cursor-aspect-ratio: 0.05; }
```

You can make the cursor even thicker by changing 0.05 to a higher number (0.1, 0.2, ...).

I did not find a method to change the color of only the text cursor.

[Source](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/153104/lo-writer-on-linux-change-appearance-of-typing-cursor-ie-not-mouse-cursor/)